# Multiple actions within a controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Currently I have a controller which is named (Manage). I want it to have links such as

```
Manage/Users/{userid}/{manageType}
Manage/Pages/{pageid}/{manageType}
```

Where the action manageType can be (Settings, Username, Description).

What is the best way to structure this in my Manage Controller so I can have all these attributes? Is it possible for there to be multiple actions functions that was within other actions? For example

```
ManageController
-> viewResult Users(int userID)
-> viewResult Pages(int pageID)
-> viewResult Type(string typeID)
```

Where the Users and Pages will point to the type after it gets the ID's from the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Is it possible for there to be multiple actions functions that was within other actions?"
How would that work? Action methods are just regular .NET methods - actions within actions don't really make sense.

If you want it all in one controller, you will have to have something like this:

```
public ActionResult UserSettings(int userid) { /*...*/ }
public ActionResult UserName(int userid) { /*...*/ }
public ActionResult UserDescription(int userid) { /*...*/ }
public ActionResult PageSettings(int userid) { /*...*/ }
public ActionResult PageName(int userid) { /*...*/ }
public ActionResult PageDescription(int userid) { /*...*/ }
```

You could wire up routing like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "Manage/Users/{userid}/Settings",
                defaults: new { controller = "Manage", action = "UserSettings" },
                constraints = new { userid = @"\d+" }
            );
```

etc.

Comment: You could do something like that, but you have left out the userid, so it is no longer part of the URL and the constraints have no effect. If you want userid passed as a query parameter then what you have is ok, though the constraints won't work